# Java Android - Access variables outside addValueEventListener

Tags: java, android, class, methods

I want to know how to access the variable `totalAmount` outside the `mDatabase.addValueEventListener`.

```
    //This is inside onCreateView
    mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            totalAmount=0;

            for (DataSnapshot mySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Transaction transaction = mySnapshot.getValue(Transaction.class);
                totalAmount += transaction.getAmount();
            }
            String total_amount = String.valueOf(totalAmount);
            totalAmount.setText(total_amount);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    TextView.setText(String.valueOf(totalAmount))
```

I can't find proper solution. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `total_amount` globally. Please change your `code` like below:

```
 String total_amount = ""
 mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            totalAmount=0;

            for (DataSnapshot mySnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Transaction transaction = mySnapshot.getValue(Transaction.class);
                totalAmount += transaction.getAmount();
            }
            total_amount = String.valueOf(totalAmount);
            totalAmount.setText(total_amount);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    TextView.setText(total_amount)
```

Comment: I already tried this, but the final value (after totalAmount += transaction.getAmount();) is not accessible outside mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {}

Comment: I couldn't see the final keyword in your code. remove the final keyword and try